# Update XML element with LINQ to XML in VB.NET

Tags: xml, vb.net, linq-to-xml

I'm trying to update an element in the XML document below:

Here's the code:

```
Dim xmldoc As XDocument = XDocument.Load(theXMLSource1)
        Dim ql As XElement = (From ls In xmldoc.Elements("LabService") _
                Where CType(ls.Element("ServiceType"), String).Equals("Scan") _
                Select ls.Element("Price")).FirstOrDefault


        ql.SetValue("23")
        xmldoc.Save(theXMLSource1)
```

Here's the XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--Test XML with LINQ to XML-->

<LabSerivceInfo>

  <LabService>
    <ServiceType>Copy</ServiceType>
    <Price>1</Price>
  </LabService>

  <LabService>
    <ServiceType>PrintBlackAndWhite</ServiceType>
    <Price>2</Price>
  </LabService>

</LabSerivceInfo>
```

But, I got this error message:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Error line:ql.SetValue("23")
```

Can you show me what the problem is? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`xdoc` is the document itself and only contains the root element.  Therefore, `xmldoc.Elements("LabService")` doesn't return anything.

You need to write `xmldoc.Root.Elements("LabService")`.

By the way, the best way to write the `Where` clause is `Where ls.Element("ServiceType").Value = "Scan"`